# Importing functions does not seem to work

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm quite new to python and still learning. I am currently have some difficulties using the import function in python. `script2.py` contains functions that enable me to use my OLED display. I currently have problems as when `def primitives` is called, I get an error that says it has not been defined.

The functions from this script (`script2.py`) are what I want to import to `script1.py` (primitives, main):

```
import time
import datetime
from luma.core.render import canvas


def primitives(device, draw):
    # First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
    padding = 2
    shape_width = 20 
    top = padding
    bottom = device.height - padding - 1
    # Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
    x = padding

    # Write two lines of text.
    size = draw.textsize('World!')
    x = device.width - padding - size[0]
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 4, x + size[0], top + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.rectangle((x, top + 16, x + size[0], top + 16 + size[1]), fill="black")
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 4), 'Hello', fill="cyan") 
    draw.text((device.width - padding - size[0], top + 16), 'World1!', fill="purple") 
    time.sleep(5)


def main():
    from luma.core.interface.serial import spi
    from luma.core.render import canvas
    from luma.oled.device import ssd1351
    serial = spi(device=0, port=0, gpio_DC=20)
    device = ssd1351(serial)
    device.width=128
    device.height=128
    print("Testing basic canvas graphics...")
    for _ in range(2):
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            primitives(device, draw)
            print("Drawing stuff 1")
    time.sleep(3)



    print("Testing clear display...")
    time.sleep(1)
    device.clear()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The script that is importing these functions (`script1.py1`) is:

```
import time 
import otherscript


variable_intermediate=1

while True:
    if variable_intermediate==1:
        from script2 import primitives, main #does not seem to work
    main()
    primitives (device, draw) #error printed in terminal, it says draw not defined
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: "does not seem to work" *how*? Obviously just importing the functions won't do anything, you actually need to call them - which you only do in the third snippet.

Comment: When you import `from script2 import primitives, main` in your script you allow the first script to access theses function but if you want to run them you have to call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : 
Script1.py

```
import time 
import otherscript


variable_intermediate=1

while True:
    if variable_intermediate==1:
        from script2 import primitives, main 
        main() # this is the line you're missing
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean. I now added `main()` and `primitives (device,draw)`

Comment: But I got another error: `NameError: name 'draw' is not defined`

Comment: Isn't draw already defined when I imported and call `main()`?

Comment: The line with `primitives(device, draw)`

Comment: That's normal, draw is not defined in script1.py, you should start primitive() from the script2.py
But that is already what you are doing in your definition of main(), you call `primitives(device, draw)`. Why do you call it twice ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163875/discussion-between-gwendal-grelier-and-craver2000).

Comment: Does that mean adding`primitives(device, draw) to `script2.py` after the functions are defined?